# Can i change ASP.Net 2.0 default blue theme to some other built in themes in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax, master-pages

i have heard that there are more themes in asp.net other than the default asp blue header theme, can any one tell me how to change it to some other theme. How can we open asp.net themes and select them for our website, please help.

Thanks
Atif

Comment: what? This makes absolutely no sense at all

Comment: if you dont know the answer, why you are saying this does not make sense and voting it down.

Comment: you do not specic if you are talking about web styles or out of the box project themes - there is not enough detail to determine what type of themes you are looking for

Comment: I want to change CSS themes for asp.net, by default it comes with blue header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this with a quick search on google. [Sample themes](http://www.dotnettreats.com/samplethemes/) and how to use them

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MvcContrib Template Gallery](http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Comment: I think its ASP MVC, do you know themes compatible with asp.net 2.0 web application?